# convert x values to minutes or hours

Tags: gnuplot

assuming I have data values like those:

```
8.31
8.25
8.13
8.06
8.00
7.94
7.88
```

and it is known that they were taken 30 seconds apart each, how can I plot them as minutes or hours in the x axis? I am just confused by not having a separate time column and hpoing gnuplot can do that without adding a new time column to the data file...

I currently use only:

```
plot 'data.log' u 0:1 with lines lw 2
```

which of cause give a dimensionless x axis...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the first point starts at time zero, you can just multiply the pseudo column with 30 to get seconds, e.g.:

```
plot 'data.log' using ($0 * 30):1 with lines linewidth 2
```

Output:

[image: Plot with x axis tics showing seconds]

As mentioned by *Dan* in the comments, if you want minutes just divide by 60:

```
plot "data.log" using ($0 * 30 / 60):1 with lines linewidth 2
```

[image: Plot with x axis tics showing seconds]

Comment: This would plot it vs seconds. Just do more math in the `using` part if you want minutes or hours. For example: `using ($0 * 30 / 60):1` for minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
reset session

TimeInterval = 30
set xdata time
set format x "%tH:%tM"

plot 'data.log' u ($0*TimeInterval):1 with lines lw 2
```